# Emacs extension specific keybinding

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a keybinding to comment current line which goes something like this for python.

```
(fset 'comment 
      (lambda (&optional arg)
    "Keyboard macro."
    (interactive "p")
    (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ("^A^[f^[b#" 0 "%d")) arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x /") 'comment)
```

How can I use the same keybinding  on multiple languages say python and cpp? Is there anyway to identify the filetype and execute the keybinding accordingly?

Comment: You might already be aware of this but if you mark one or more lines, you can hit `M-;` (the default binding for `comment-dwim`) to comment out the entire region (or *uncomment* it if it was commented out before). This works out of the box in any programming language mode I've ever come across...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the keybinding only to a specific keymap:

```
(eval-after-load "python-mode"
    '(define-key python-mode-map "\C-x/" 'comment))
```

Comment: Using this in my .emacs raises this error:
`Symbol's value as variable is void: python-mode-map`

Comment: @AshokaLella: Check the update. You have to modify the keymap later once it really exists.

Comment: thanks, using `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda () (define-key python-mode-map "\C-x/" 'comment-line)))` solved the problem.

Comment: `define-key` is a one time configuration, so I think it's better to use `eval-after-load` as answered.